# How to update maven jar to war in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm currently studying maven and I just made "maven-archetype-quickstart" and set the compile properties to 1.8

Then I wanted to change the jar to war so I changed packaging to war.

I also checked `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Import Maven projects automatically`

and I've tried `Maven -> Reimport All Maven Projects`
but the projects structure doesn't change.
How can I update the maven package 'jar' to 'war'?

[image]

Comment: The project's structure isn't supposed to change. The only thing that changes is taht when you `mvn package`, the result will be a .war file and not a .jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project structure in IntelliJ reflects the stucture of folders/files in the filesystem. That shouldn't change. More precisely, both `jar` and `war` packaged modules are allowed to have `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java`, `src/test/resources`

This is a standard maven layout.

However, in addition WAR projects can have `src/main/webapp` folder where you can place JSP files, `web.xml` descriptor (inside inner `WEB-INF` folder) and so on.

Since you didn't create those folder, visually you won't be able to see the difference.

If you have an ultimate edition of intelliJ IDE, you can configure tomcat plugin to run the WAR on pre-installed tomcat server (or use other alternatives for running WARs).

In order to learn the impact of packaging, you can run `mvn package` from the command line and examine the created artifact in the `target` folder